# SQL - How to answer this question : List employees who were hired on Tuesday and sort them from Z to A

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on something. I have tried everything....

```
SELECT last_name, hire_date
FROM employees
WHERE TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'DAY') = 'TUESDAY'
ORDER BY last_name DESC;
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong? Do you get an error?  Does it produce the wrong answer?  please try to provide sample data and describe what problem you're having

Comment: Zero errors. I tried with other days of the week and everytime my result list is just empty.

Comment: Try moving TO_CHAR part to the select portion of the query, and temporarily get rid of the WHERE clause.  Do you see any that say TUESDAY?

Comment: ```SELECT last_name, TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'DAY') = 'TUESDAY' 
FROM employees 
ORDER BY last_name DESC; ```

Now I get error "FROM keyword not found where expected" :-(
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alter session set nls_territory = 'AMERICA';

SELECT last_name, hire_date
FROM employees
WHERE TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'DAY') = 'TUESDAY'
ORDER BY last_name DESC;

Try with alter session

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `fm` format modifier to your TO_CHAR, like this:

```sql
SELECT last_name, hire_date
FROM employees
WHERE TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'fmDAY') = 'TUESDAY'
ORDER BY last_name DESC;
```

Oracle adds padding to the right of the string to match the length of the largest element (in this case, 'Wednesday'.) Using the `fm` format modifier will suppress the blank padding.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle adds with `TO_CHAR` a space at the end, so you need to trim it, so that your comparison works

> ```
> CREATE TABLE employees
>     (id int,
>      hire_date date,
>      last_name varchar2(20));
> ```

> ```
>  insert into employees
>     select rownum, trunc(sysdate) -10 + rownum, 'mylastname' || rownum
>     from dual
>     connect by level <= 20;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT last_name, hire_date,TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'DAY')
> FROM employees
> WHERE TRIM(TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'DAY')) = 'TUESDAY'
> ORDER BY last_name DESC;
> ```
>
> ```
> LAST_NAME    | HIRE_DATE | TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DAY')
> :----------- | :-------- | :-----------------------
> mylastname7  | 12-JUL-22 | TUESDAY                 
> mylastname14 | 19-JUL-22 | TUESDAY
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=76137a5c36a85a13a4ddde212536b6e2)*